# Compare hours in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

first of all my english is not really good.

I want to write a script in HTML where i can make a login access between 21:00 (9 PM) till 6:00 AM.

```
function myFunc() {

        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();

        var stunde = [21, 22, 23, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

        var s1 = document.getElementById("field1").value;
        var s2 = document.getElementById("field2").value;

        if (h == stunde) {
            if (s1 == s2) {
                if (s1 != '' && s2 != '') {
                    window.location.href = 'default.html';
                }
            } else window.alert("Veuillez insérer les données correctement.");
        }
    }
```

Is my **If**-Statement not correct? Maybe should i use a **for(; ;)**?

Thanks for considering my request :)

\o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (h == stunde)` should become `if (stunde.includes(h))`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I use your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are missing a `{` for your `else` statement.

After adding that in, you'll want to make sure that your logic can actually be triggered after the fields have been entered. For this, I've moved the functionality into a function that gets called on click of a button.

You'll probably also want an `else` conditional for when the time isn't valid; currently nothing happens in this situation.

Finally, your first conditional that compares the time to the array needs to check that the value is **within** the array, not exactly equal to the array itself. This can be done with 
 `if (stunde.indexOf(h) > -1)` (or the more intuitive ES6 method **[`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)**).

This can all be seen in the following:

```js
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();

var stunde = [21, 22, 23, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var s1 = document.getElementById("field1").value;
var s2 = document.getElementById("field2").value;

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (stunde.indexOf(h) > -1) {
    if (s1 == s2) {
      if (s1 != '' && s2 != '') {
        window.location.href = 'default.html';
      }
    } else {
      window.alert("Veuillez insérer les données correctement.");
    }
  } else {
     window.alert("Time not valid.");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="field1">
<input id="field2">
<button>Go</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post.

Comment: In place of if (stunde.indexOf(h) > -1), i use if (stunde.includes(h)) and it works perfectly.